# How to enhance template with additional .phtml file?

Tags: template, layout

my .phtml file which lists 3 products in a row is:

```
frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

This file includes also the following .phtml files to include more information.

```
frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
frontend/base/default/template/germansetup/price_info.phtml
```

I now want to include a custom attribute between these two files price.phtml and price_info.phtml. How can I kind of "hook" into it and include another .phtml file? I know that this works with a XML file - but where/how can I find the correct XML file and how I can include my own .phtml file there?

Would be great if anybody can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming you want to add these to the search results page, but this could work for any other layout handle.

Firstly you will need the layout handle in my assumption `catalogsearch_result_index` is the value you need.

You then need to find the name of the block that is using the `product/list.phtml` template. In my assumption it is the name `search_result_list`.

Now what you can do is using these two items of knowledge and a local.xml file in your theme simply add a new child block.

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="search_result_list">
         <block type="core/template" name="your-new-name" templte="path/to/your/template" />
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Then in your product list template you can call `getChild` to get this block. You can then set your attribute against it using `setData` and then call `toHtml` to get the display.

```
$_yourBlock = $this->getChild('your-new-name');
$_yourBlock->setData('your_attribute', $product->getData('your_attribute'));
echo $_yourBlock->toHtml();
```

A slightly "nicer" way would be to use a block type that extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` and then you can set the product against it and call toHtml. A perfect example of this is the `getPriceHtml` which takes a product object, sets an template and then calls the toHtml.

```
public function getPriceHtml($product)
{
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/price.phtml');
    $this->setProduct($product);
    return $this->toHtml();
}
```

One final and maybe simple suggestion is to simply not use a template for the single attribute and include it direct in your theme's product list.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for this extensive explanation. I am not referring to a search result, when the user clicks on the category in the main menu he will see those three products in one row. 
How do I find now the right xml explanation like <catalogsearch_result_index><reference name="search_result_list"> to hook in between those two phtml files?

Comment: to find the layout handle you can look at the body class when viewing the source in the browser. This is often the layout handle but with - and not _

Comment: I assume you mean: catalog-category-view / In the catalog.xml in my theme folder I can only find <default> and <catalog_category_default translate="label"> so I assume I should create <catalog_category_view> and add the template? But how can I define that it should be between the other two .phtml files mentioned above?

Comment: customize the template so it calls the block in the right place

Comment: Hey David, do you know a good tutorial that shows how I customize and enhance a template in the right way...?